# how to apply maxlength attribute in angular mat-select-autocomplete search filter input?

Tags: angular

[[image: I want apply max length to mat-select-autocomplete as shown in the figure but i don't see any pre defined attribute. ][1]]

I want apply max length to mat-select-autocomplete as shown in the figure but  don't see any pre defined attribute. Can you please provide. added the link .

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-autocomplete-and-maxlength-issue-track

Comment: Can you please provide what was wrong in my question who disliked/unusual I can update the same. It is a project requirement i have created the stackblitz url for the same.

Answer (score 1):

This library dont have option for set maxlength.

[image]

I suggest you import the library locally into your project and edit directly to add your option or change to another.

last option but not the most recommended, get the element in the dom and modify it directly :

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = document.querySelector("mat-select-autocomplete");
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const input = document.querySelector(".box-search input[type=text]");
      if (input)
        input.setAttribute("maxlength", "4");
    });
  }
```

We need add a listener because input text is create only when you click on the component for open overlay.

Comment: this.yourDomElement.setAttribute('maxlength', 4);  Can you please provide working example.